# Why does the fork process seem to end my program early

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

I am attempting to use child processes in C++ and communicate between the two of them using piping, I think I have the right idea but am running into a weird error after the do while loop where it just ends the process. why is this happening and what can I do to fix it. The one cout check I have is my test, it shows up if I delete everything afterward that line but not otherwise.  What would I do to fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string password;
    string discovery;
    int fd[2]; // One for the child to write to the parent
    //int reversefd[2]; // Another for the parent to write to the child

    if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
        cout << "Cannot create pipe";
        exit(1);
    }

    //if(pipe(reversefd)<0){
    //cout <<"Cannot create pipe";
    //exit(1);
    //}

    pid_t chPl;

    cout << "Enter the password(no spaces): ";
    do {
        cin >> password;

        if (password.length() > 20) {
            cout << "Enter a password with less than 20 characters: ";
        }
    } while (password.length() > 20);
    cout << "check";

    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    cout << password << endl;

    chPl = fork();
    if (chPl < 0) //Nothing was created
    {
        cout << "Unable to make child";
        exit(2);
    }
    else if (chPl == 0) //In the child process
    {
        string attempt;
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        cin >> attempt;
        cout << attempt;
    }
    else // Parent
    {
        wait(0);
        cout << "parent function started again";
    }
}
```

Comment: Some indentation would make your code readable to humans.

Comment: You close `fd[0]` before the fork.  Then the child does `dup2(fd[0],0)`.  Check the return status of the dup2.  It is almost certainly failing.

Comment: William thank you, that helped me find the problem and I got it working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I closed it too early and that made it fail quickly, I rearranged the code, putting the close statement right above the wait.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



using namespace std;
int main(){

    string password;
    string discovery;
    int fd[2]; // One for the child to write to the parent
    //int reversefd[2]; // Another for the parent to write to the child

    if(pipe(fd)<0){
    cout <<"Cannot create pipe";
    exit(1);
    }

//if(pipe(reversefd)<0){
//cout <<"Cannot create pipe";
//exit(1);
//}

    pid_t chPl;


    cout << "Enter the password(no spaces): ";
    do {
        cin >> password;

        if(password.length() > 20){
        cout << "Enter a password with less than 20 characters: ";
        }
        }
    while(password.length() > 20);


    chPl=fork();
    if(chPl<0) //Nothing was created
        {
        cout << "Unable to make child";
        exit(2);
        }
    else if(chPl==0) //In the child process
    {
        string attempt;
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        cin >> attempt;
        cout << attempt;
        }
    else // Parent
    {
        cout << "check";
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        cout << password<< endl;
        wait(0);
        cout << "parent function started again";
        }

    }
```